# Nesting CSS based on class of body

Tags: css

I have multiple themes for my website, such as a light or dark theme. This is applied via a class to body. I would like to apply certain styling if body has dark.

I have tried this:

```
body.dark {
    .sidebar {
        background-color: #444;
    }
    .intro {
        background-color: #CCC;
    }
    /* etc */
}
```

However, none of the styles are applied. What would be the correct way to this condition?

I can do .sidebar.dark, however the current dark CSS file is in .intro, .sidebar, etc.

Comment: That's not valid CSS. You can't nest selectors this way. You may have gotten the impression that this is possible from one of the various CSS preprocessors like SASS and LESS, which add the ability to nest selectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such nesting/scoping in pure CSS. You'll have to write `body.dark` over and over again.

```
body.dark .sidebar {
    background-color: #444;
}
body.dark .intro {
    background-color: #CCC;
}
```

- P.S - It is possible in dynamic stylesheet languages like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) and [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use comparison functions directly on CSS without a preprocessor like **[SCSS](http://sass-lang.com/)** or **[LESS](http://lesscss.org/)**. So in this case I'd recommend simple Javascript. The fastest way is to use some JQuery magic.

You can achieve this by using the following lines, for example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if($('#div').attr('background-color') === 'black'){
      // do something if its black
   } else if($(#div).attr('background-color') === 'white'){
      // do something if its white
   }
});
```

Basically it is verifying what color is your #div's background-color, and if it is black, you can make something happen, if it is white, you can have a different action going on.